# problem accessing to a variable in object

Tags: php, arrays, object

Edit: this is part of main function to call the grab function:

```
  $video['type']          = $videoProvider;
  $video['id']          = $videoIds;
  $video['title']          = $this->grab_title_from_curl($data);
```

I have this little function to parse title from html via curl, it works.

```
  private function grab_title_from_curl ($pull){
    preg_match("/<meta name=\"title\" content=\"(.*?)\"/", $pull,$data) ;
    return $data;
  }
```

and shows me this:

```
Array
(
    [type] => yahoo
    [id] => 613478/2923165
    [title] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  EXELENTE TIRO DE ARCO!!
        )
)
```

I need to [title] directly gets the value of [0] in the array.
like:  [title] => EXELENTE TIRO DE ARCO!!

second edit:

for some reason the code breaks when i use JoostK's code: 
[pastie.org](http://pastie.org/1132696)

sorry for my bad english!

**SOLVED:** instead of preg_match("/?)\"/", $pull,$data);
preg_match('/?)\"/', $pull,$data) ;

Comment: The array you show can't be the `$data` array. Easiest but not most elegant way would be to use `$array['title']=$array['title'][0];` There may be better ways to do it, but then we need a bit more code.

Comment: don't works! i've tried a lot of ways but i cant make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your edit, this should work:

```
private function grab_title_from_curl ($pull){
    $data = array();
    preg_match("/<meta name=\"title\" content=\"(.*?)\"/", $pull, &$data);
    return $data[0];
}
```

Comment: don't works, and also breaks the array:
<code>
Array
(
    [type] => yahoo
    [id] => 613478/2923165
    [title] => 
</code>

Comment: it breaks again! any new idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use a temporary variable to hold the matches:

```
private function grab_title_from_curl ($pull){
    $matches = array();
    preg_match("/<meta name=\"title\" content=\"(.*?)\"/", $pull, $matches) ;
    $data['title'] = $matches[0];
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: don't works shows me an empty array, but if delete the [0] part i got:
[title] => Array
        (
            [title] => Array
                (
                    [0] =>  EXELENTE TIRO DE ARCO!!

Comment: Based on your new edit I see how you're doing it. In that case JoostK's answer above should be correct. It's good practice to declare your variables before using them.

Comment: greenbandit: Try removing the ampersand (&) before the $data variable in JoostK's code above.

Comment: The ampersand is there because I pass the variable by reference. In PHP it doesn't matter (as far as I know) whether you do it or not, however now I can clearly see that the variable is a reference, not having to look it up in the documentation.